# Make Jekyll Site Pages with Inverted Background

Tags: jquery, css, rubygems, jekyll, blogs

I have a simple question and I couln't find answer on the web.

I am trying to use this theme https://alshedivat.github.io/al-folio/

But it has white background.

I want it inverted i.e. black background.

Like the one that I can get in my browser by using an extension like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en

Is it possible in Jekyll? How to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Use this (additional) CSS:

```
body, a, p {color: #fff;}
body, .site-header {background: #333;}
```

Place it at the bottom of the main.css file.

Comment: Hi, the color of links is appearing pink now... how to change that and one more thing, can I increase the contrast of the black background?

Comment: You can fine-tune this by changing the css color values. Add `a {color: white!important;}` to change the link color.